# Xcode 7: Is there a method to invalidate all timers?

Tags: nstimer, invalidation

I'm making a game where you can play stage 2 and jump back to stage 1. But the game runs with timers. Is there a method to invalidate all NSTimers?

Like (just made this up):

```
[NSTimer invalidateAllTimers];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such a method.  If there was, it could break a lot of things because your code isn't the only code that can use timers.  Frameworks can too.

However, you can keep an NSMutableArray of all the timers your game is using and invalidate all the timers in the array, like this:

```
//whenever you create a timer:
[timers addObject:timer];    //timers is the NSMutableArray of all your timers
//when you invalidate a timer:
[timers removeObject:timer];
//to remove all timers:
[timers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(invalidate)]
[timers removeAllObjects];
```

Note: I have not tested this code, and it could cause problems if you put duplicate timers in the array.

Answer (score 3):

There is no method to invalidate all timers. You need to store the timer reference in an array and then you can do fast enumeration and invalidate them all .

For example:

```
for (id timerObject in timerObjectsArray) {
    if ([timerObject isValid]) {
        [timerObject invalidate];
    }
}
```